# java.util.UUID.fromString not checking length

Tags: java

When I looked into the implementation of `java.util.UUID.fromString`, I found that it doesn't check for the UUID length. Is there any particular reason for this? It only checks the components separated by "-".

```
String[] components = name.split("-");
        if (components.length != 5)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid UUID string: "+name);
```

Should it also throw IllegalArgumentException when length is not 36?

Currently, without the length checking, numbers are automatically prepended with 0's if less than the component length or shifted if more. The downside is, if one entered a UUID string with a missing digit, it is accepted as valid and prepended with 0. This is hard to debug.

For example, this "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789ab" becomes "12345678-1234-1234-1234-0123456789ab". Notice the '0' added? And this "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abcd" becomes "12345678-1234-1234-1234-23456789abcd" with the '1' removed.

To push this even further, the string "1-2-3-4-5" will also be treated as valid and becomes "00000001-0002-0003-0004-000000000005".

Edit: To clarify my question, is this a bug or done on purpose to follow some standard or principle?

Comment: So, what exactly is your question? You know how `UUID.fromString` works, you've looked at its source code. Apparently it doesn't check the length of the parts. So what kind of answers do you expect here?

Comment: It seems (part of) this behaviour was fixed somewhere between Java 8 and Java 11, the too long segments are no longer accepted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Only the original authors of the UUID class could tell you why they chose not to check the component lengths in the fromString method, but I suspect they were trying to heed [Postel's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postel%27s_law):

> Be liberal in what you accept, and conservative in what you send.

You can always check the input against a regular expression like this one:

```
[0-9a-fA-F]{8}(?:-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}){3}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}
```

Answer (score 12):

The behaviour of UUID.fromString is strange I am not sure if it is a bug or not, but here is what I have been doing to catch those errors.

```
public class UUIDUtils {
    public static boolean isValid(String uuid){
        if( uuid == null) return false;
        try {
            // we have to convert to object and back to string because the built in fromString does not have 
            // good validation logic.
            UUID fromStringUUID = UUID.fromString(uuid);
            String toStringUUID = fromStringUUID.toString();
            return toStringUUID.equals(uuid);
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Best practice states that you should only use exceptions for exceptional occurrences.

Comment: It's a one-liner in Clojure (such a pretty language):
`(try (= uuid (.toString (UUID/fromString uuid))) (catch IllegalArgumentException false))`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

```
import java.util.UUID
import scala.util.control.Exception._

val uuId: Option[UUID] = allCatch opt UUID.fromString(uuidToTest)
require(uuId.isDefined, "invalid UUID")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to test against `id.equalsIgnoreCase(parsed.toString())` because `UUID.fromString(id)` returns lower case even if you pass `id` as upper case.

```
@Component
public class UuidDtoValidator {

    public boolean isValidUuid(String id) {
        if (isBlank(id)) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            UUID parsed = UUID.fromString(id);
            if (parsed.equals(new UUID(0, 0))) {
                return false;
            }
            return id.equalsIgnoreCase(parsed.toString());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A copy of ams's answer but for scala xD

```
def isValidUuid(uuid: String): Boolean =
    try uuid != null && UUID.fromString(uuid).toString.equals(uuid)
    catch {
      case e: IllegalArgumentException => false
    }
```