# How to check a whether string value belongs to UUID or not in java/android?

Tags: java, android, uuid

In my program I am using a line  as follows to generate a string UUID

```
final String value= UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

suppose I get the given sting value as UUID string

```
581572cb-d8bb-49f9-a664-9d692a7c7a87
```

**How can I make sure that the received string belongs to a correct UUID ?**

I already visited,

[java.util.UUID.fromString not checking length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768510/java-util-uuid-fromstring-not-checking-length)

to  have the answer, but still not sure what to use what to do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **regex**: `[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}` to check a valid **UUID**.