# Why are two different java.util.UUID objects comparing as equal?

Tags: java, uuid

I have created two instances of `java.util.UUID` as given below. One is created from `UUID.randomUUID()` and the other is the same but with some additional digits prepended to the beginning. When these are compared using the `UUID.equals` method it returns `true`:

```
UUID uuid1 = UUID.randomUUID();
UUID uuid2 = UUID.fromString("12345"+uuid1.toString());
System.out.println(uuid1.equals(uuid2));  // this gives true.
```

I think the added digits are being discarded and both give the same UUID string value. Why this is happening?

Comment: UUID represents a 128-bit value. Surely "12345"+uuid1.toString() exceeds that capacity and is internally truncated by UUID.fromString(..) method. You can try print uuid1.toString() and uuid2.toString and test with a smaller uuid1.

Comment: Looking at the source for `UUID.fromString()' , the extra part you have added gets included in the first component of the UUID (That is the part before the first '-').
This then gets shifted out to the left, and a load of other things as well, so the original string gets used. Take a look at the source code to see what I mean

Comment: Why they equal is understandable. Real question is why part sizes of the stringUUID.split("-") are not validated. But as someone said here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9771512/3020903, it's probably a design decision that no one else but the implementors of this code know.

Comment: Thank you @jr593

Comment: Thank you @Tarmo

Comment: Because that's an incorrect way to construct an UUID, so behavior is undefined. The real question is why would you do something like that.

Comment: @m0skit0, The reason for using this way is that I am using UUID as the resourceId in my restful web service URI. When I tested the service by giving some additional digits as I explained above, I got a success response which was not an expected result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the UUID.fromString(...) method you have this:

```
public static UUID fromString(String name) {
    String[] components = name.split("-");
    if (components.length != 5)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid UUID string: "+name);
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        components[i] = "0x"+components[i];

    long mostSigBits = Long.decode(components[0]).longValue();
    mostSigBits <<= 16;
    mostSigBits |= Long.decode(components[1]).longValue();
    mostSigBits <<= 16;
    mostSigBits |= Long.decode(components[2]).longValue();

    long leastSigBits = Long.decode(components[3]).longValue();
    leastSigBits <<= 48;
    leastSigBits |= Long.decode(components[4]).longValue();

    return new UUID(mostSigBits, leastSigBits);
}
```

The first thing it does it to separate the parts of the UUID into components, then it will create two longs. Here you changed only the first component of the UUID by adding leading characters, your UUID string is for example "**12345**894ff97a-039b-47fe-8a72-950b7766d50c". So the first component is "**12345**894ff97a", when it will do

```
long mostSigBits = Long.decode(components[0]).longValue();
```

Then you will have "320256540146042" which actual HEX representation is "**12345**894ff97a", then you have a bit operation that will shift the long 16 bits to the left:

```
mostSigBits <<= 16;
```

This will result in "2541588541301456896" which actual HEX representation is "**2345**894ff97a0000" (we moved 16 bits so 4 hex chars) and you start to see what is happening, see the long format is only 64 bits, so when shifting the bits some are lost, here the first character "1" is lost. After that in the freed space it will add the second component:

```
mostSigBits |= Long.decode(components[1]).longValue();
```

This will result in "2541588541301457819" which actual HEX representation is "**2345**894ff97a039b", then it will shift the long 16 bits to the left again:

```
mostSigBits <<= 16;
```

This will result in "-8552342864911466496" which actual HEX representation is "894ff97a039b0000" and here your leading characters are all lost because of the long 64 bits size.

I don't need to explain the rest of the method (at the end mostSigBits is "894ff97a039b47fe" and leastSigBits is "8a72950b7766d50c"), you can already understand that any leading character added to an UUID will be lost when calling UUID.fromString(..) since only the last 8 hex characters (32 bits) are going to be considered, the rest is going to be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not creating two differing UUIDs.

`UUID.fromString("12345"+uuid1.toString());` does not make sense: `UUID.fromString(String)`requires the passed String to adhere to the 'string standard representation' as described in `UUID.toString()`. See [UUID.fromString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#fromString(java.lang.String) and [UUID.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString()).

I wonder why you won't get an exception, but I guess your first few chars are ignored.

Comment: "That won't work" is a false statement. It does. You are not answering the question, you are just reasking it from a different angle by saying: "I wonder why you won't get an exception..."

Comment: @Tarmo What I was trying to say: Constructing a new UUID that way won't work (it also makes little sense regarding how UUIDs work). And I disagree that I am re-asking the same question by merely stating that I wonder why there is no exception because the input to `fromString()` is clearly not valid.