# UUID.fromString(var) is accepting additional characters in Java

Tags: java, java-8, uuid

I have a requirement where I accept a UUID and check whether the UUID is in valid format or not. Package `java.util` provides a `UUID.FromString(var)` method which accepts a variable and it throws an exception when it is not in valid format.

For some unknown reasons, it's accepting an additional character and filters it out instead of throwing an exception.

For example,

```java
String var1="BAAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA"
UUID.fromString(var1)
```

Here, there is an additional character B but instead of throwing an exception, it's filtering it out as "AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA".

Can anyone help me understand why is this happening?

I am using Java 8.

Comment: This results in a _"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UUID string too large"_ (Java 17.0.4). Exactly which Java version are you using.

Comment: I run your sample code and it throws this exception: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UUID string too large". do you sure it works wrong for all inputs or just on specific input that you don't mention it?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am using Java8.

Comment: @MTB Its specifically ignoring the first digit and passing it as valid. e.g., Cc21a392e-3da6-4cd4-ac9f-9d963b313e22

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour in Java 8 Update 332, so it seems to be a bug that was fixed in later versions.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [java.util.UUID.fromString not checking length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768510/java-util-uuid-fromstring-not-checking-length)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yeah, it seems like it is ignoring the length of the UUID. Thanks for the help! I am new on StackOverflow.

Comment: So (for the java 8 bug) also check that the lenght ' 8+1+4+1+4+1+8 = 27. // Comment it

Comment: @JoopEggen Yeah, I have added an additional check for length for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Historically, it looks like Java's `UUID` class has been very lenient in what it accepts. This includes too short segments, and too long segments. This behaviour was tightened up somewhat between Java 8 and Java 11 (I didn't want to check Java 9 or 10 to see exactly when), as Java 11 no longer accepts your example (but still accepts too short segments).

I haven't been able to identify the exact bug in the Java bug database that changed this, but there are a lot around this behaviour (example: [JDK-8216407 : java.util.UUID.fromString accepts input that does not match expected format](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8216407)), but most of them are either still open, closed as duplicate, or marked as "won't fix" because of backwards compatibility concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I double-checked (javac 11.0.15)

- and it is behaving as expected.

Here is an example of how I tested it:

I guess that you are not handling the exception properly.

```
class Example {
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Valid case
        System.out.println(isValidUUID("AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA"));
        // Invalid cases
        System.out.println(isValidUUID("Cc21a392e-3da6-4cd4-ac9f-9d963b313e22"));
        System.out.println(isValidUUID("BAAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA"));
        System.out.println(isValidUUID("AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA"));
        System.out.println(isValidUUID("Hope this helps"));
        
    }
    
    /**
      Check if a supplied UUID is valid
    */
    public static boolean isValidUUID(String uuid) {
        try {
            UUID.fromString(uuid);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please try this UUID?
Cc21a392e-3da6-4cd4-ac9f-9d963b313e22
btw I am using Java8.

Comment: Which Java version did you use to check.

Comment: I am running javac 11.0.15

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with this

```
String uuid = jsonObject.get("uuid").get("id").toString();    
UUID originalId = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(uuid.getBytes());
```